# Exception raised when filtering NSManagedObjects with NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data

In short, I don't think I'm formatting the NSPredicate correctly.

Given an array of NSManagedObjects, I want to construct a new array containing objects where an attribute matches a certain value.  In this case, where the attribute `status` is equal to the value "inactive."

`parentObject` is the parent entity in my core data object model.  An ivar passed in from the previous controller.  It's also already been fetched via a previous controller.

`theRelationship` is a one-to-many relationship also defined in the model with entity type `ChildEntity`.

```
NSSet *theRelatedObjects = [parentObject valueForKey:@"theRelationship"];  
NSArray *unfilteredObjects = [theRelatedObjects allObjects];  
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == inactive"]; 
NSArray *filteredObjects = [unfilteredObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];   
//at this point NSUnknownKeyException is raised.  
//error message:  the entity ChildEntity is not key value coding-compliant for the key "inactive"
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status like 'inactive'"];
```

Comment: Gah.  So simple.  Apparently I did not read the NSPredicate documentation closely enough.  I love this website!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Is 'status' a string? Try something like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status == %@", @"inactive"];
```